# Flutter: Semantics for Dialogs - VoiceOver reads out "dismiss"

Tags: flutter

I try to add VoiceOver support to my app. I faced the following problem:

Always **when I open a dialog the VoiceOver reads out "dismiss"** before it reads out the dialog content.

Example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title),),
      body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Open Dialog"),
            onPressed: (){
              showDialog(context: context,
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Close"),
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              )
              );
            },
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

VoiceOver-Output: "dismiss close button"

When I add 'barrierDismissible: false,' the VoiceOver-Output changes to "close button".

**Is there a way to change the "dismiss" output to some other value?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `showGeneralDialog` instead of `showDialog` method.
You can then set a value to the `barrierLabel` property.

Voice over will read the `barrierLabel` property instead of the "dismiss" you have in the `showDialog`.